# PHP MVC paradigm, should i bother?

Tags: model-view-controller, yii, php

i come seeking a little guidance.

over the last 18 months or so i have been teaching myself PHP & Jquery and must admit that i have become somewhat good at it :-).

I have developed a few decent webapps / websites that work really well but one thing that always pops up is these frameworks such as yii.

I have never used the MVC paradigm before but am starting to consider it as i see many "pros" use it.

I have developed my own style in the last 6 months that i find works well (build a php file say api.php and using jquery ajax calls to interact with it and the front html, whilst building a html front end the good old fasioned way)

Now my questions are these:

- should i bother to learn a framework/MVC?
- is it considered more professional / better?
- what benefits / disadvantages can i expect?
- which framework should i start off with?

I know this seems like a lot to ask but i would really appreciate some help on this matter

Comment: Oh ignore it, ignorance is bliss!

Comment: even though the question is interesting, it will probably be closed. You might want to google "why use a php framework". Good Luck

Comment: Answer to your first question: **yes**. The others are too subjective, toy around, and find your own answers :).

Comment: Using MVC is a `best practice` in modern web-oriented development. You'd better follow it, but it's up to you to decide. Regarding frameworks, there are already a bunch of questions about it on SO (this site :)), so try searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, before super users of SO exercise their super powers, let me share my experience with you. A framework

- takes away the pain of reinventing the wheel
- bothers about security
- makes your app distribute-able as a code with lesser problems
- ease of deployment
- ease of scaling, if you follow the rules correctly
- ease of maintenance and management, again if you follow the rules correctly
- makes you follow some standards, good for you
  and many many more. Thy shalt google for more.

Comment: you could also make a list having the same length which covers all the negativ things about a framework :)

Comment: duedl0r, I had that list with me some time back, but looking at the good things I threw away the list, there is no silver bullet but frameworks do work out better when you have to get a prototype done quickly

Comment: lol SO super users.  FIGHT THE POWER!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article on PHP frameworks just a few days ago: http://www.factor3.co.uk/blog/web-frameworks.  This will show you the benefits of using frameworks.

Regarding MVC design pattern.  The main benefit of this is that it separates the different parts of your code into logical parts.  This is useful in numerous situations.  Eg. you might have different people working on each part.  It also allows you to easily change the display of an application, without affecting the functionality.  Having an MVC breakdown is also useful as your application scales.

Comment: and to you also, many thanks for your input, i will read your article